# Xcode 7.1.1 break point

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.1

I had downloaded XCode 7.1.1

When I put the break point and run the application, instead of going to breakpoint line of the code, its showing something like in the screen and also when there is a crash at that time debug is coming like this.

I would like to know how to goto the line of the code and also how to check in which line the crash is taking place.

Can anyone help me, I had enabled Address Sanitizer then also its not going to the code

[image]

Comment: have you added an "exception breakpoint"?

Comment: I tried but its not going to the exact break point during the run time

Comment: not just set "a breakpoint", but an **exception breakpoint**!? That is something different. A regular breakpoint gives you nothing if the code crashes before reaching it,

Comment: Yex Exception Breakpoint only I added by clicking + symbol